# How do I fix flutter cloud_firestore dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on flutter app testing out cloud_firestore.
My app works just fine until I added "cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0" into my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore:
```

I have tried to change version of cloud_firestore to 0.8.2 or even not include version at all. but I still cannot get it to work.
I have also tried to change minSdkVersion in "android\app\build.gradle" from 16 to 21.

```
  defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.baby_names"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

And this are errors messages.

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\BeatMil\MakeApp\baby_names\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :cloud_firestore

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.
> Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for 9rdd22t0lqqejbejjys4b4x3q (C:\Users\anuto\.gradle\caches\4.10.2\scripts-remapped\build_d998a31vo7rwlu75ja03b8zq8\9rdd22t0lqqejbejjys4b4x3q\cp_proj70b1361a260e0ceb212a59c45f680ebd).
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
  Command: D:\BeatMil\MakeApp\baby_names\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

My app would not launch anymore. I need help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: does your app use androidX

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: update your app to use androidX and then try using cloud firstore v 0.12.9+3

Answer (score 1):

Update: So I change cloud_firestore version to 0.3.0 and it worked.

I think it might be related to sdk version. I'm not sure. I'm no expert.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.3.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```